# Subspaces of $M_2(\Bbb{F})$ where $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{R} \;\text{or}\; \Bbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be the  set of $2 \times 2$ matrices $ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ with complex entries  such that $a_{11} + a_{22 }=0$.
>
> Let $W$ be the  set of matrices in $V$ such that $a_{12}  + \bar{a_{21}} =0$, then under the usual matrix addition  and scalar multiplication, which of the following statement  is (are) true?
>
> - a) $V$ is a vector space  over  $ \mathbb{C}$
> - b) $W$ is a vector space  over $\mathbb{C}$
> - c) $V$ is a vector  space over $\mathbb{R}$
> - d) $W$ is a vector space  over  $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt:

For option  `a)` I take  $ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}= a_{11}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}+ a_{12}\begin{bmatrix} 0& 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + a_{21}\begin{bmatrix} 0& 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

here $a_{11} ,a_{12},a_{21},a_{22} \in \mathbb{C}$  so  V  is  a vector space  over $\mathbb{R}$

I am confused about option b) , c) and d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straightforward verification yields $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$.

For a sake of simplicity, Identify $$M_2(\Bbb{C})\sim \Bbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$$

Then  $$V=\Bigg\{ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} \in M_2(\Bbb{C}):  a_{11} + a_{22 }=0\Bigg\}$$
can be written as $$\Bigg\{  (a_{11} , a_{12}, a_{21} , a_{22})\in \Bbb{C}^4: a_{11}+a_{22}=0\Bigg\}$$

Which is same as $$\Bigg\{ (a_{11} , a_{12}, a_{21} , a_{22})\in \Bbb{C}^4:\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{12}\\ a_{21} \\ a_{22} \end{pmatrix}=0\Bigg\}$$ 
 which exactly the homogeneous solution of the system: $Ax=0$

where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{12}\\ a_{21} \\ a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ and so it is a subspace of $M_2(\Bbb{C}) $, which means it is a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$

Can you conclude the others?

Comment: im not  able to clear,the other,i was thinking  that  every  real number  is  a  complex number ...

Comment: according  to ur  answer all option a) b)  c) and d) all  are true